# Strange behavior of <apex:pageBlockSectionItem>, field label is not coming up

Tags: visualforce

I have noticed one strange thing about `apex:pageBlockSectionItem` that if i put a inputField  or selectList under pageBlockSectionItem its label gets disappear. I don't know why is this happening? Can anybody explain this.

```
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:outputLabel value="Expiration Date (Mo/Yr)"></apex:outputLabel>
              <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
              <apex:selectList value="{!expDate}" size="1">
                 <apex:selectOptions value="{!dates}"/>
              </apex:selectList> 
         <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
```

I have find out one work around of this by putting up a outputLabel block just before inputField as shown in above example. can anybody explain the best way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: I am completely new to SF. But, in the code block, is line 3 a typo/paste error?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a bug or problem. It works exactly as designed. Here is a piece of [official salesforce doc](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_pageBlockSectionItem.htm):

> Note that if you include an `<apex:outputField>` or an `<apex:inputField>`
>   component in an `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`, these components **do not
>   display with their label** or custom help text

To "workaround" this case if using an `<apex:inputField>` just use no pageBlockSectionItem and the label will be rendered automatically:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:inputField value="{!someObj.val__c}" />
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

In your case i would use this example:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
   <apex:outputLabel value="Expiration Date (Mo/Yr)"/>
   <apex:selectList value="{!expDate}" size="1">
       <apex:selectOptions value="{!dates}"/>
   </apex:selectList> 
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```